# What is the meaning of this shloka on Brahmacharya?

Tags: translation-request, brahmacharya

What is the meaning of this shloka?

Karmana manasa vaca
Sarvavasthasu sarvada
Sarvatra maithuna-tyago
Brahmacaryam pracaksate

I got this shloka from [here](https://vivekavani.com/swami-vivekanandas-quotes-on-brahmacharya/)

Comment: The meaning is explained in the link itself- karmana- by actions, manasa- by mind, vacasa- by speech, sarvavasthasu- in all states, sarvada- always, sarvatra- everywhere, maithuna tyagah- abandonment of sex, brahmacharya pracakshate- is called Brahmacharya. By actions, by mind, by speech, in all states, always, everywhere, abandonment of sex is called brahmacharya.

Comment: @Archit link have the answer I don't why this question

Comment: @PrasannaR yes the link has the answer that’s why I put a comment stating that, instead of posting an answer